# What is this function do internally of Time Lock Controller of Solidity?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, smart-lock

```
   function hashOperation(
    address target,
    uint256 value,
    bytes calldata data,
    bytes32 predecessor,
    bytes32 salt
) public pure virtual returns (bytes32 hash) {
    return keccak256(abi.encode(target, value, data, predecessor, salt));
}
```

I am unable to understand address target is written for what purpose?

Comment: Do you know what hash functions are? [What are Hash Functions and How to choose a good Hash Function?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-hash-functions-and-how-to-choose-a-good-hash-function/)

Comment: I think it creates the hash of the operation and its data and that hash will be used as the Id of the operation.

Comment: Yes but what are these address target,
    uint256 value,
    bytes calldata data,
    bytes32 predecessor,
    bytes32 salt
are used for ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this information in the doc of OpenZeppelin for v.4.x [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#TimelockController)

First, what is an operation? it is a transaction (or a set of transactions) that is the subject of the timelock. It has to be scheduled by a proposer and executed by an executor [here](http://Operation:%20A%20transaction%20(or%20a%20set%20of%20transactions)%20that%20is%20the%20subject%20of%20the%20timelock.%20It%20has%20to%20be%20scheduled%20by%20a%20proposer%20and%20executed%20by%20an%20executor)

the hashOperation function: Returns the identifier of an operation containing a single transaction [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#TimelockController-hashOperation-address-uint256-bytes-bytes32-bytes32-).

An Operation contains [here](http://operations%20contain:%20%20Target,%20the%20address%20of%20the%20smart%20contract%20that%20the%20timelock%20should%20operate%20on.%20%20Value,%20in%20wei,%20that%20should%20be%20sent%20with%20the%20transaction.%20Most%20of%20the%20time%20this%20will%20be%200.%20Ether%20can%20be%20deposited%20before-end%20or%20passed%20along%20when%20executing%20the%20transaction.%20%20Data,%20containing%20the%20encoded%20function%20selector%20and%20parameters%20of%20the%20call.%20This%20can%20be%20produced%20using%20a%20number%20of%20tools.%20For%20example,%20a%20maintenance%20operation%20granting%20role%20ROLE%20to%20ACCOUNT%20can%20be%20encode%20using%20web3js%20as%20follows:%20%20const%20data%20=%20timelock.contract.methods.grantRole(ROLE,%20ACCOUNT).encodeABI()%20Predecessor,%20that%20specifies%20a%20dependency%20between%20operations.%20This%20dependency%20is%20optional.%20Use%20bytes32(0)%20if%20the%20operation%20does%20not%20have%20any%20dependency.%20%20Salt,%20used%20to%20disambiguate%20two%20otherwise%20identical%20operations.%20This%20can%20be%20any%20random%20value.%20%20In%20the%20case%20of%20batched%20operations,%20target,%20value%20and%20data%20are%20specified%20as%20arrays,%20which%20must%20be%20of%20the%20same%20length.):

**Target**: the address of the smart contract that the timelock should operate on.

**Value**: in wei, that should be sent with the transaction. Most of the time this will be 0. Ether can be deposited before-end or passed along when executing the transaction.

**Data**: containing the encoded function selector and parameters of the call. This can be produced using a number of tools. For example, a maintenance operation granting role ROLE to ACCOUNT can be encode using web3js as follows:

> const data = timelock.contract.methods.grantRole(ROLE,
> ACCOUNT).encodeABI()

**Predecessor**: that specifies a dependency between operations. This dependency is optional. Use bytes32(0) if the operation does not have any dependency.

**Salt**: used to disambiguate two otherwise identical operations. This can be any random value.

Comment: Do you have links to any blogs where these Smart Contract applications are used?

Comment: No, but maybe the written test could help to understand it more https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/test/governance/TimelockController.test.js